# GPS position correction

Tags: gps

I wrote simple NMEA parser and I'm reading latitude and longitude from GPS. Values readed by my parser are very scattered comparing to some GPS commercial library I'm using. Values readed from this library are very smooth.

What algorithms I should use to correct readed position from gps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)

Answer (score 1):

GPS Signals read from a GPS receivers are today only scattered, if the receiver
 is standing still, or moving very slowly.

A simple and very effective approach is to ignore all positions which have its speed attribute below 5km/h.
This works well for vehicles.
For pedestrians it gets more complex.